# ¿Como Guardar Los Token De Firebase En Mi Base De Datos?

Tags: firebase, notificaciones

Cree una aplicación y estoy usando firebase cloud messaging para enviar notificaciones a los usuarios que la instalen, lo que quiero hacer es guardar el token de cada dispositivo en mi base de datos para así poder enviar notificaciones a un usuario en especifico.
Les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran...

Comment: Hola Angel, te sirvio mi respuesta debajo ? si es asi no olvides marcarla como correcta, un saludo :)

Comment: Estoy trabajando con flutter por lo que no e podido resolver ese problema. Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Existe una clase singleton llamada `FirebaseInstanceId` la cual podes usar para obtener el token del usuario que esta logueado

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Obtenemos el token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                // Mostramos el token
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Luego de obtenerlo , debajo de la linea `String token = ...` podes enviar ese token a la base de datos con por ejemplo `mDatabaseRef.child(user_id).child("device_token").setValue(token);`

Para mas info visita la documentación

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client